# Obtaining GPS location in FileMaker application

Tags: gps, filemaker

I am working with my local historical society, and they want to document headstones in the town cemetery.  I propose to create a FileMaker application/form, which will allow the operator to visit each headstone, record the information, including its location by clicking a form button.

I am looking to answers to these specific questions:

1. Is it possible to plug a USB GPS receiver into the Surface, and have its location information get to the FileMaker application?
2. Is it possible to click a button on the custom application/form, and have the GPS location stored in the current record for the gravestone?
3. Code snippet to illustrate capturing the XY location data upon pressing a form button, and storing it in the current record.

I have searched the FileMaker Web site and manual, and elsewhere on the Web, but haven't found many clues as to how this can be done.  Sure hate to reinvent the wheel!

Operating conditions include:
Windows Surface Pro with Windows 10 up to date;
FileMaker Pro v14

Comment: Questions seeking tool recommendations are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, so I've edited your question to remove that bit (pending approval). You might be able to get help for that over on the [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange.

Comment: FileMaker Pro has no access to the device's location (unlike FileMaker Go). You may be able to get at it through OS-level scripting. I suggest you ask this in one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.

Comment: You can use "Insert from URL" to call a webpage that will return the GPS location.  E.g.: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp  There are plenty of external GPS receivers that work with Windows, you will have to do some shopping to find one, they could be USB or Bluetooth. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/bluetooth-gps-receiver-on-windows-10/bb3c8c70-a898-4269-a6c3-c72a64e18b2d?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker's [`Location`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Flocation.html%23) and [`LocationValues`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Flocationvalues.html%23) functions could be useful if your client is open to using FileMaker Go on an cellular iPad or an iPhone. If this is an option, a button that executes a script to get the coordinates is trivial:

```
// Transform comma separated coordinates to a list of coordinates
Set Variable ( $_location ; Substitute ( Location ( 100 ) ; ", " ; "¶" ) ]
Set Field [ Gravestones::latitude ; GetValue ( $_location ; 1 ]
Set Field [ Gravestones::longitude ; GetValue ( $_location ; 2 ]
```

Baring that, my next suggestion would be to use an Internet connected Surface, although being less familiar with Windows, I'm not sure of the best way to do that. If the Surface is connected to the Internet, then you can use a WebViewer to access the geolocation. [The Support Group](http://www.supportgroup.com/blog/geolocation-with-filemaker-go/) has an example of how  to do so, or CSchwarz's suggestion from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp) would also be an option.

Finally, and this is probably going to be ugly, if you're truly limited to a Surface with no Internet, then you'd probably need to connect a [GPS USB device](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gps%20usb&atb=v48-7_s&ia=products) and either use a Plugin such as [Troi Serial](https://www.troi.com/products/serialplugin/) with an [adapter of some sort](https://fmforums.com/topic/68780-getting-the-weight-from-a-usb-scale/?tab=comments#comment-326266) or use batch files to communicate between FileMaker what some other app that can read the data.